# I'm trying to reverse some stuff written in a text file in python using stacks

Tags: python, stack

Reversing a string from a text file in Python

I tried the code below because I was trying to push in the reversed order of the months but it returns none

```
 import TStack as Stack


f=open('months.txt','r')

data=Stack.create()

for line in f:
    Stack.push(data,line)

while not Stack.is_empty(data):
    removed=Stack.pop(data)
    here=Stack.push(data,removed)

list returns None
```

Comment: That code doesn't return or output anything, and contains nothing called "list".

Comment: Popping something from a stack and then pushing it back is the same as doing nothing.

Comment: Why do you think you should put them back in the stack? Remove the pushing, add `print(removed)`, and see what happens.

Comment: @molbdnilo- how do I put these stuffs that I popped out of my list and then put them into the stack?

Comment: @molbdnilo- It returns me the elements of the stack in reversed order. So Is another stack creation necessarry to reverse the strings?

Comment: And is that not your goal?

Comment: Oh so my first goal is done then? Because I'm also trying to reverse each character of the text

Comment: Please add a more precise description of your goal to the question.

Comment: print(removed) returned September October November December

May June July August 

January February March April     but I'm trying to get an out put which is lke this: rebmetpeS rebotcO rebmevoN rebmeceD
yaM enuJ yluJ . tsuguA
yraunaJ yraurbeF hcraM lirpA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stack to write a string-reversal using the same procedure as you do for reversing the lines:

```
import TStack as Stack

def reverse_string(s):
    stk = Stack.create()
    for c in s:
        Stack.push(stk, c)
    result = ""
    while not Stack.is_empty(stk):
        result += Stack.pop(stk)
    return result



f=open('months.txt','r')

data=Stack.create()

for line in f:
    Stack.push(data,line)

while not Stack.is_empty(data):
    print(reverse_string(Stack.pop(data)))
```

You could also reverse each line as you add it to the stack;

```
# ...

for line in f:
    Stack.push(data, reverse_string(line))

while not Stack.is_empty(data):
    print(Stack.pop(data))
```

Comment: Oh Thanks @molbdnilo! I'll try some of this out!